# Separate Metadata for Parts of pdf

Tags: pdf, metadata

I've scoured the Interwebs without success.  I know that basic metadata can be added to the pdf catalog using various packages, and have used `pdfx` especially for this.  I have no difficulty putting into the final pdf metadata concerning the entire document.

However, I'm now typesetting a volume of multiple independent works, which share no metadata other than being put in the same volume.  They have different titles, authors, different copyright statuses, and so forth.  Is it possible to include metadata for each individual part of the volume?

E.g., in addition to the information about the document as a whole (say, "Great American Short Stories"), can I include data about the individual stories within it (say, "Young Goodman Brown," "The Fall of the House of Usher," and so forth)?

Comment: As far as I know, there are only two meta data sections in a `.pdf` file

Comment: Can one insert sub-dictionaries of metadata into it?  E.g., one element of the metadata dictionary is another dictionary containing "Young Goodman Brown," "Nathaniel Hawthorne," and so forth?  And if so, are there packages to do it with?

Comment: @dgoodmaniii: No. And the old metadata concept is being replaced with XMP lately. Btw: The relationship of this question to TeX is thin.